# How do I make use of the Criteria API to find a specific person based on different criterias?

Tags: java, database, jpa, criteria-api

I love all the help I've gotten in the past simply by reading your topics, however I've now stumbled onto something I literally have no idea how to implement at all.

**Edit: Forgot a big portion -> My framework: I'm running this on Netbeans, using Glassfish server with EJB and the DB being run on a MySQL server. Also I'm making use of JPA.**

I have a database which contains several tables, but there's 3 that I need to use a join on, to get people that match the criterias out of it.

My database:
[image: My database]

I'll try to simplify what I'm trying to do, might actually help me get some insight in this while I'm typing.

I'm trying to

- Find all pid in Availability where the dates that a user sends in is inbetween. Example:
  User sends in Period 2010-10-10 to 2011-01-01, I'm trying to find all pid where, in Availability, the from_date is "higher than" or past 2010-10-10 and the to_date is lower than or not past 2011-01-01.
- Find all pid in Competence_profile where competence_name is the name sent in by the user, and the years_of_experience is at least equals to or greater than the years of experience that the user sends in.
- Join them somehow so that I get Person p from the Person-table, that matches the pid that remained from the join (meaning, the pid existed in both Availability and Competence_profile for the criterias).

How do I do something like this based on the Criteria API? I played around with it awhile and read quite a lot of tutorials and topisc, but none were able to actually answer my question as to how I combine it in this form.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is with Hibernate Criteria API.

```
     // First set up a subquery to get the ids of Persons who are available
     // (assuming that the Person must be available for the entire duration)
     DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Person.class)
         .setProjections(Projections.id())
         .createAlias("availability", "a")
         .add(Restrictions.le("a.to", endDate)
         .add(Restrictions.ge("a.from", startDate);

     Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Person.class)
          .createAlias("competence", "c")
          .add(Restrictions.eq("c.name", competenceName)
          .add(Subqueries.in(dc,"id");

     List<Person> people = crit.list();
```

Comment: Man, thank you so much for answering but I knew I forgot to mention something in my post, which is actually a huge thing -> The framework. I'm running on Glassfish, having the DB on a MySQL server and using EJB, and ofcourse JPA.

Comment: No problem Devil. You should be able to translate this solution into JPA Criteria API. The db shouldn't matter.